# Browser of file

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I'm trying to develop a file browser in Qt and C++.

Opening a FileSystem can take a lot of memory. In that way, the best is to only open what is inside a folder when I click on it.

In my browser.h, I have declared the OnClick signal.

```
class Browser : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Browser(USBDevice dev, QWidget* parent = 0);
        QTreeWidget(parent)
        {
            connect(this , SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)),this,
                 // SLOT(showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
        };
        ~Browser(){};
     public slots:
        void showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int /*column*/)
        {
         ...
        }
};
```

QTreeWidget is failing to build saying : 
error: function definition does not declare parameters - QTreeWidget(parent)

in the browser.cpp, I have wrote the code to create window, widget..

```
Browser::Browser(USBDevice dev, QWidget *parent) :
    QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

    window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("PULS"));
    window->resize(400, 400);

    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(window);
    QTreeWidget *MyTree = new QTreeWidget(centralWidget);
    MyTree->setFixedSize(395,395);
}

//Set QTreeWidget Column Header
QTreeWidgetItem* headerItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
headerItem->setText(0,QString("File Name"));
headerItem->setText(1,QString("Size (Bytes)"));
headerItem->setText(2,QString("Date"));
MyTree->setHeaderItem(headerItem);
```

I don't understand but How to manage connect ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `;` instead of a `:` before the initialiser list for your constructor:

```
Browser(USBDevice dev, QWidget* parent = 0);    // <--- here
    QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    ...
```

---

FWIW, I recommend putting the colon at the start of the line like this:

```
Browser(USBDevice dev, QWidget* parent = 0)
  : QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    ...
```

That way it's much clearer how the second line relates to the first and third, and you'll get in the habit of editing the declaration when you go to make it a definition, avoiding the kind of problem you had.